# Large/clear row names for heatmap in R

Tags: r, heatmap, hierarchical-clustering

I have a matrix with 100 cases.
Is it possible in R to produce heatmap with labels larger than row height with something like arrows or pointers? For example there can be more than one column with labels on the right side of the heatmap.

This is my result for pheatmap library:
[image]
I would like to have labels which are at least 4 times larger.

Below is my drawing - example of diagram with colour marks/ticks for labels 3x larger than row height:
[image]

That is the best idea I have at this moment.

Comment: Could you mock up a few rows of an example of your goal using Paint or some other editing software? I'm confused how you expect to fit labels that are 5x larger in anything close to the same amount of space.

Comment: Columns width can be smaller, and let say we only try to print 2x larger labels. In first column we can have odd IDs, in second even IDs with different colours and maybe row (or part of the row border) can be marked somehow in the appropriate colour. Maybe arrows/pointers are not the best idea.

Comment: Okay. Can you share a small reproducible example for us to work with? Maybe even whatever command you used from the `pheatmap` package has an example that would be suitable?

Comment: I called `pheatmap(as.matrix(df), color = my_palette, breaks = color_breaks,...)` from pheatmap. It can be any other library that handles heatmap generation.

Comment: People are much more inclined to help if there's a reproducible example--including sample data--that they can copy/paste. Sharing code to simulate fake data, using built-in data, or using `dput()` to make a copy/pasteable version of existing data are all good options.